# Change reference to inner struct, or is it possible to change the reference of a reference in rust

Tags: pointers, rust, mutable-reference

I'm currently trying to translate a C program to Rust.

The C programm has following structures (boiled down to MRE):

```c
typedef struct {
    bool isActive;
    uint32_t value;
} tMyInnerStruct;

typedef struct {
    tMyInnerStruct inner1;
    tMyInnerStruct inner2;
} tMyStruct;
```

and in a function I would do the following pointer magic:

```c
void myFunction()
{
    tMyStruct myStruct = initMyStuct();
    tMyInnerStruct *pActiveInner = &myStruct.inner1;
    // Do something with pActiveInner (pointing to inner1), like setting value...
    changeActiveStruct(&myStruct, &pActiveInner);
    // Do something with pActiveInner (pointing to inner2), like setting value...
}

void changeActiveStruct( tMyStruct *pMyStruct, tMyInnerStruct **ppActiveInner )
{
    if ( &pMyStruct->inner1 == *ppActiveInner ) {
        *ppActiveInner = &pMyStruct->inner2;
    } else {
        *ppActiveInner = &pMyStruct->inner1;
    }
}
```

No my question is: How would I achieve the same in Rust?

What I've tried so far in Rust:

```rust
#[derive(Default)]
struct MyInnerStruct {
    is_active: bool,
    value: u32,
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct MyStruct {
    inner1: MyInnerStruct,
    inner2: MyInnerStruct,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn change_active(&mut self, active: &MyInnerStruct) -> &mut MyInnerStruct {
        if &self.inner1 as *const _ == active as *const _ {
            &mut self.inner2
        } else {
            &mut self.inner1
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut my_struct: MyStruct = Default::default();
    let mut active = &mut my_struct.inner1;
    active = my_struct.change_active(active);
    // The above complains, that my_struct cannot be borrowed mutable more than once...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accompilsh the same thing by using a pointer as argument instead of a reference. Because of the order that arguments and the receiver are evaluated in, you have to convert to a pointer ahead of the call and can't do it in the parameter list but this works:

```rust
impl MyStruct {
    fn change_active(&mut self, active: *const MyInnerStruct) -> &mut MyInnerStruct {
        if &self.inner1 as *const _ == active {
            &mut self.inner2
        } else {
            &mut self.inner1
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut my_struct: MyStruct = Default::default();
    let mut active = &mut my_struct.inner1; 

    active = { 
        let active = active as *const _;
        my_struct.change_active(active)
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3c652edb9f8479077e7027480e38514f)

---

<sub>Minor detail, `change_active` does no longer seem like an apropriate name since the Rust version doesn't actually change `active` maybe `new_active` or something else still is a better name for the method</sub>

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was searching for :-)
The cast during the comparison was already a hint, but I'm not so familiar with the pointers in Rust.
The only drawback in my opinion, is the scoped shadowing of the active variable, as it's not a one-liner ;-)